# ContextMenuOpening event is raised even if the control has no ContextMenu defined

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Consider the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ContextMenuEvent.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" ContextMenuOpening="Window_ContextMenuOpening">
    <Grid>
        <Button>Ok</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Right-clicking the button causes ContextMenuOpening to fire, even though no context menu actually appearing.

Why is it happening? What can I do to get an even only when a context menu is REALLY opening?

I am aware I can use [ContextMenu.Opened](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.opened.aspx) event, but this will only cover a single context menu, and I want to cover all the (existing) context menus in the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not so sure why you'd use this approach.  You can however easily check if a context menu would appear.  Like this:

```
    private void Window_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e) {
        var menu = (e.Source as FrameworkElement).ContextMenu;
        if (menu != null) {
            // etc..
        }
    }
```

Comment: Err. What approach you mean? What approach can I use instead to know when a context menu is opening? Regarding your idea:

Answer (score 0):

You would the source element of the ContextMenuEventArgs parameter, and cast it as a System.Windows.Controls.Control (or something as generic as that which would cover all clicks). You can then check the ContextMenu property.